# Does perlin noise have a grid of black spots (valuating near 0)

Tags: calculus, geometry, signal-processing, noise

As far as I understand, perlin noise is made by creating a grid/lattice with some vertices $\mathbf v'$, choosing an arbitrary gradient vector $\mathbf{g_{v'}}$ over each vertex of the grid.  To evaluate at a point $\mathbf x$ of space, we first compute the dot product of the "shift vector" $\mathbf x - \mathbf v$ from $\mathbf x$ to a vertex $\mathbf v$ of the cube/square of the grid containing $\mathbf x$.  Then an interpolation is done over all the vertex of the cube containing $\mathbf x$, using an interpolation function $c_{\mathbf v}$ on the dot product $\big( \mathbf v - \mathbf x \big| \mathbf g_{\mathbf v} \big)$ that evaluates $0$ over all the other different vertices $\mathbf w \ne \mathbf v$ of the cube.

We end up with something like

$$
\mathrm{perlin}(\mathbf x) = \sum_{\mathbf v\in \mathrm{enclosing}(\mathbf x)} c_{\mathbf v}(\mathbf x) \cdot \big( \mathbf v - \mathbf x \big| \mathbf g_{\mathbf v} \big)
$$

However I have trouble understanding why this algorithm gives so good results.  If we evaluate the noise at a vertex point exactly, then the distance vector $\mathbf v - \mathbf x$ to that vertex is $0$ so the end result should be $0$, regardless of the value of the gradient $\mathbf g_{\mathbf v}$.

But when I look at a perlin noise, I dont' see a regular pattern of black areas in perlin noise, how is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing a little bit more with Perlin noise, I realized it did have that grid of values at $0$, except that perlin noise actually yields *negative* values as well and the result is scaled to $[0,1]$, so the grid is actually not black (value $0$), but mid-grey (value $\frac{1}{2}$) which is much less noticeable.

Comment: the Perlin noise [looks like a grid](http://pygame.org/shots/1044.png) when unzooming, for avoiding that you can add different Perlin noises at different zoom level, or add some filtered white noise to it, or any texture you like